# How do I properly parse a JArray into a collection of strings

Tags: c#, arrays, json, .net, json.net

So I got this `JArray` stored in a variable of type `object`

```
public object Errors { get; }
```

which contains either this

```
Errors = {[
  {
    "name": [
      "Username &quot;admin&quot; has already been taken."
    ],
    "email": [
      "Email is not a valid email address."
    ]
  }
]}
```

Or it's going to contain this

```
Errors = {[
  "User not found."
]}
```

And I want to be able to extract the data like this.. `email: "Email is not a valid email address."`

And I'm not sure how to do it, and this is what I have so far

```
foreach (var error in (JArray)Errors)
{
    System.Console.WriteLine($"Type: {error.Type}");
}
```

How do I properly extract the errors so I get a collection containing the strings either like kvp or `email: "Email is not a valid email address."`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like this?

```
static List<string> ExtractErrors(JArray array)
{
    JToken item = array.FirstOrDefault();
    if (item.Type == JTokenType.Null)
    {
        return new List<string>();
    }
    if (item.Type == JTokenType.Object)
    {
        return item.Children<JProperty>()
                   .Select(jp => jp.Name + ": " + (string)jp.Value.FirstOrDefault())
                   .ToList();
    }
    return new List<string> { item.ToString() };
}
```

Here is a demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/md1oyn

Comment: That's amazing! Such a clean solution and I love how you decided to use LINQ!

Comment: Glad I could help!